What does the sum of reciprocals of all "pentachoron" numbers converge to?
For those of you who don't know, in order to understand what a "pentachoron" number is you need to understand what a tetrahedral number is, and in order to understand what a tetrahedral number is, you need to understand what a triangular number is. (I have pentachoron in quotations because I don't know if this set of numbers has an actual name or not).
A triangular number is the sum of all natural numbers from 1 to a given natural number. 1 is the first triangular number. 3 (or 1+2) is the 2nd triangular number. 6 (or 1+2+3) is the 3rd triangular number. 10 (or 1+2+3+4) is the 4th triangular number, and so on.
A tetrahedral number is the sum of all triangular numbers from 1 to a given triangular number. 1 is the first tetrahedral number. 4 (or 1+3) is the 2nd tetrahedral number. 10 (or 1+3+6) is the 3rd tetrahedral number. 20 (or 1+3+6+10) is the 4th tetrahedral number, and so on.
A pentachoron number is the sum of all tetrahedral numbers from 1 to a given tetrahedral number. 1 is the first pentachoron number. 5 (or 1+4) is the 2nd pentachoron number. 15 (or 1+4+10) is the 3rd pentachoron number. 35 (or 1+4+10+20) is the 4th pentachoron number, and so on.
So for this infinite sum you'd have is
(1/1)+(1/5)+(1/15)+(1/35)+(1/70)+(1/126)+(1/210)+(1/330)+(1/495)+(1/715)+(1/1001)+(1/1365)+(1/1820)+(1/2380)...
From my calculations, this value is roughly 1.33. My conjecture is that this infinite sum converges to 4 thirds.

Yes, $$\sum_{n=4}^\infty \frac{1}{\binom{n}{4}} = \frac{4}{3}.$$

See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2251543/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2938484/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3312607/42969.

Duplicate target and similar questions found with Approach0
